# What is most efficient way to find difference between two databases in CouchDB (based on one field)?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, nosql

I have databases A and B that contain few millions entries (CouchDB).

What is most efficient way to find entires from A that are not present in B based on one field (nrs)? The size of the difference is about 45000 elements.

Sample entry:

```
{
   "_id": "000560f149160c986552726a46000c24",
   "_rev": "1-e2f7c260865fb55353a2ce3d666ab662",
   "nrs": "14,15,22,64,67"
}
```

Comment: Do you have to do this in real time of is it just a one time deal?

Comment: Are you looking for a NodeJS solution? I am asking, because it cannot be achieved by using CouchDB alone.